# docker compose up 'unable to access jarfile'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i trying run my application with docker

Dockerfile

```bash
FROM openjdk:latest  
CMD ["./mvmw", "clean", "package"]  
COPY target/doIt-0.0.1.jar app.jar  
RUN chmod 755 app.jar  
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  application:
      container_name: doIt_service
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      volumes:
        - ./:/app
      working_dir: /
      command: ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
      restart: always
```

it works
but

1. app.jar is position root directory
2. all files of project in /app/

so i changed file

```bash
FROM openjdk:latest  
CMD ["./mvmw", "clean", "package"]  
COPY target/doIt-0.0.1.jar /app/app.jar  
RUN chmod 755 /app/app.jar  
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

and

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  application:
      container_name: doIt_service
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      volumes:
        - ./:/app
      working_dir: /app
      command: ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
      restart: always
```

than i type
`docker compose up`
its not work!!
(err message : "Unable to access jarfile /app/app.jar")

i browse "view file" in docker and show file is right location
'app/app.jar'

why is not work?
what is my fault?

i want to change /app.jar to /app/app.jar

i don't like "app.jar" in root directory

Answer (score 2):

You are copying the jar to /app/app.jar, but after that in the docker-compose.yaml you are mounting volume in /app, which replaces all the contents, and app.jar is not there anymore.

- One solution is to remove the volume, if you need only the jar and not other files from the source code

```
version: '3'

services:
  application:
      container_name: doIt_service
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      working_dir: /app
      command: ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
      restart: always
```

- Another option is to use different directories for the jar and /app for the jar and /code
- Another option is to copy the content of the app and remove the volume from docker-compose.yaml

```
CMD ["./mvmw", "clean", "package"]
RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY ./ /app
COPY target/doIt-0.0.1.jar /app/app.jar
RUN chmod 755 /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  application:
      container_name: doIt_service
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      working_dir: /app
      command: ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
      restart: always
```

Comment: it works toooo.
1. remove "COPY" and the "ENDPOINT" in Dockerfile   
2. edit docker-compose.yml  
    command: ["java", "-jar", "/app/target/doIt-0.0.1.jar"]
running success

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) in the Dockerfile.  This sets the current directory, so both the directory that `COPY` will copy into and the current directory when you say `java -jar app.jar`.  I'd put that directive before the first `COPY` line.  `WORKDIR` creates the directory if it does not exist and you do not need to `RUN mkdir`.

```bash
FROM openjdk:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/doIt-0.0.1.jar app.jar  
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

You also do not need to `RUN chmod` the file (you are not directly running it as `./app.jar`), nor do you need to set a `CMD` (arguments that get passed to the `ENTRYPOINT`).

In the Compose file, in turn, you need to delete the `volumes:` block that replaces `/app` in the image and injects the content you don't want.  You have several other unnecessary options as well.  I'd trim this down to just

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  application:
      build: .
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      restart: always
```

The other options either override defaults Compose provides (`container_name:`, `build: { dockerfile: }`) or things in the Dockerfile (`working_dir:`, `command:`) and can be safely removed.